# get adjacent matrix of point in python

Tags: python, matrix, point

If in 2D, p(x,y), I'd like to have a adjacent matrix of 3*3:

```
(x-1,y-1), (x,y-1), (x+1,y-1),
...
(x-1,y+1), (x,y+1), (x+1,y+1),
```

What if in 3D(3*3*3), 4D(3*3*3*3),...?

Is there better function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also be able to use `itertools.product`, depending on exactly what output format you prefer.  It'll be slower than a `numpy` approach but I find it easier to understand:

```
from itertools import product

def adjacent_grid(centre):
    steps = product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=len(centre))
    return (tuple(c+d for c,d in zip(centre, delta)) for delta in steps)
```

which gives

```
>>> list(adjacent_grid((3,)))
[(2,), (3,), (4,)]
>>> list(adjacent_grid((3,3)))
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4)]
>>> list(adjacent_grid((3,3,3)))
[(2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 4), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 3), (3, 4, 4), (4, 2, 2), (4, 2, 3), (4, 2, 4), (4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 3), (4, 3, 4), (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result by using broadcasting in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def p(*args):
    args = np.array(args)
    idx = np.array([-1, 0, 1])
    a = np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ix_(*(args[:,None] + idx)))
    return np.concatenate([x[..., None] for x in a], axis=-1)
```

The result shape is (3,3,2) in 2D, (3,3,3,3) in 3D, (3,3,3,3,4) in 4D:

```
>>> p(3, 8)
array([[[2, 7],
        [2, 8],
        [2, 9]],

       [[3, 7],
        [3, 8],
        [3, 9]],

       [[4, 7],
        [4, 8],
        [4, 9]]])
```

Comment: what if i use res.flat to iter element? i want to get point tuple instead of int

Comment: for i in p(3,8).flat: print i

Comment: You can reshape the result: `p(3, 8).reshape(-1, 2)`